# PayPal https ko

Tags: ssl, paypal, sslhandshakeexception

I have been using PayPal Express Checkout NVT API for years on an old Debian.
Now (January 2015) my Java servlet says : 
    FATAL [FatalException] Unable to complete HTTPS transaction
    javax.net.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at com.ibm.jsse2.n.a(n.java:37)
    ...
Did you change something on your side ?

Comment: "Did you change something on your side" -- who are you talking to?

Comment: @Erwin Bolwidt On the PayPal site, when you clic on "forum", they send you to StackOverflow with the tag PayPal. So, is not it natural to ask them something ?

Comment: I'm afraid that that just means that they don't want to spend too much money on supporting developers. It doesn't make the volunteers on StackOverflow to be Paypal staff...

Comment: I'm afraid you are right. I have always appreciated stackoverflow help. And I got a very useful answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid this could be due to the SSL issue, which PayPal has disable the SSLv3 support completely on January 12th due to Poodle vulnerability.

All information on the POODLE vulnerability and the changes needed can be found here:

[PayPal SSL 3.0 (POODLE) - Merchant Response Guide](https://ppmts.custhelp.com/ci/fattach/get/445843/1417414724/redirect/1/filename/Poodle%20SSL%203%200%20Vulnerability%20-%20Merchant%20Response%20Guide%20(U.S.%20English).pdf)

You can check the status and update your SDK (If needed) here:

[PayPal SSL 3.0 (POODLE) Microsite ACT NOW](https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1182)

Comment: Thanks. After you said it, it looks now obvious ! I saw the PayPal "merchant " update for POODLE, but the package organisation (.ebay.) is not at all the same as the old PayPal NVP package I use. I have to investigate further.